# How to address the issue of a vertical window that was installed horizontally

Tags: basement, windows, installation, horizontal

I assigned a contractor to install a new window at basement.
I bought the window 33x40 and material with the contractor in Home Depot. The contractor cut the wall and installed well.

Two days later I showed it to friends and found a lot water when i opened it and it was difficult to close. When e checked the window label i found "**install vertically only**".

In advance of starting, I said to position it horizontal since the Home Depot window associate said that the window can be horizontal or vertical.

Now, the contractor said that this is my responsibility, and he could come back to drill holes for drainage.

I am wondering if it's enough as a repair, and if it's a problem when to sell the house.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any contractor worth his hammer would've noticed that and brought it to your attention. The window needs to be replaced or installed vertically as intended. Whether he's liable is a contractual issue and off-topic here.

Drainage holes are not an adequate solution. The window will not continue to operate well over time. The hardware isn't designed for sideways loading. Nor are the weather seals, as you've discovered. For these reasons it may well be an issue at sale time in addition to being an operational and weather issue.

Best of luck.

Comment: my 2 Cent-after just ordering and having windows installed.  Yes - the window model can be installed with width and length in either directions, but when ordering you specify which dimition is v & h, then the window is made with  proper drainage and the window opening and closing in the horizontal direction.  If you want the windows to open in the vertical direction, you open that model, with the dimitions in the direction you want.

Comment: That's a rare feature. I don't believe I've ever seen that since the channels are usually very different for top/bottom and sides.

Comment: Agreed with Isherwood,  the flange on the top and bottom and the sides are different.  Top and bottom have added strength to support the window and design for the drainage to collect and be diverted to the bottom to exit.

Comment: I am not saying the same model,  Horizontal model opening and vertical opening style.  Not one model that does both.

Comment: In other words, why did he purchase a horizontal model and install it sideways when he should have ordered it in the proper dimensions in the V and H.

Comment: Thank you all for your advices. It's kind of pain to re-do the installation especially while the contractor believes not his fault.

Comment: @yahu "*the contractor believes not his fault*"  It is not the contractors fault if he did what you instructed him to do.

Comment: Actually I gave the space for window, he did measurement. Then went to Home Depot bought the window.  I told that I am not knowledgeable on it and you need ensure all right including city code and installation. He said that he had done hundreds window... To redo, if keep the window then it requires cut more wall below the ground in addition to fill huge gap in width which may look like a damaged. I noticed the contract with 2years warranty, how could I use it to redo the installation? Thank you all again. Yahu

Comment: @yahu Well that info was not included in your question. What else was not included?

Comment: Unfortunately, as I mentioned, contractual issues are [specifically off-topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here. You might try the [law Stack Exchange site](https://law.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: sorry for some of my questions out of the allowed topic. I learn from this website and appreciate all additives. It seems one question cannot cover the whole issue. Now the questions go further: Is there any place to order the window according to the size? How to understand and use the 2 years warranty written in the contract ? Thanks.

Comment: Again, I believe that the contractor should tell me which position for installing the purchased window is right, or any problem could be raised up if the position is in horizontally. Especially I asked him to ensure right in city code and window installation. Moreover, it is the contractor ensuring me the window fitting the space, then I signed the contract. Therefore, I believe he is liable to. I believe that a doctor cannot cut a leg just because the patient's complaint about the leg-pain and want to cut off.

Comment: Please don't continue discussion and questions in comments (especially on a resolved question). Post a new question if you like.